# connection between ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I try to use one AWS EC2 instance to start another EC2 instance automatically so that it could be started automatically if this monitoring EC2 instance keeps running.  I could use SSH to connect to my instance . However ,when I try to use ec2-start-instance . I failed with following bugs:

The instance ID 'i-XXXXXXXX' does not exist

These two instances are in different availability zone so I think it is networking settings problem but I don't know how to solve it.Anyone could help me?

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with your networking settings. When you call `ec2-start-instance` you are communicating with the AWS API, you are not sending commands to the instance itself. Are the instances in the same region? Are they in the same AWS account?

Comment: Neither the same region nor the same account

Comment: I know I am communicating with the AWS API but it requires configuration so it still has something to do with instance attributes.

Comment: I fiexed it. Thank you Mark B. It is indeed simply related to AWS API.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your answer lies in Roles.  i.e. Account A's EC2 instance needs to have a Role Right on Account B to start EC2 instances in Account B.  And it needs to somehow be assigned this role. Not sure that's possible?

Check into:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html

"The access policy for the role specifies what the role allows someone to do. For example, you could specify that the role allows someone to manage only your Amazon EC2 and Amazon RDS resources but not your IAM users or groups. In our sample scenario, you use the access policy to give Example Corp read-only access to all of the resources in your account."

Answer (score 0):

@Mark B
I fixed because I used the wrong credentials. One AWS account was set up for my personal website and the other was other uses so I considered using this continuously running instance to do something for me.

Thank you